# warning: implicit declaration of function 'system'

Tags: c

I am getting an error in my compiler:

```
Warning: implicit declaration of function 'system'
```

I added:

```
system("cls");
```

To be able to clear the screen, and now I get the error. I am using this code to test:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int nothing; //random name

int main()
{
printf("this is a msg");
scanf("%d",&nothing);
system("cls");
printf("hello");
getchar();

return 0;
}
```

This is just a test code, so it's very sloppy. I am new to coding so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should tag your question with either [tag:c] or [tag:c++], not both. As for the error, it is because `system` is defined in `stdlib.h`. So include that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For C++: `#include <cstdlib>`, for C: `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Or, you can do as follows:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus__
  #include <cstdlib>
#else
  #include <stdlib.h>
#endif

if (system("CLS")) system("clear");
```

You can also see a full article w.r.t [Clear the screen](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/4z18T05o/).

Answer (score 3):

This warning is reported when a function is called before its declaration. In your case, you haven't included the library stdlib.h at the start of your code. So the compiler sees the call to function before its prototype.

Comment: Can you add some valuable link to make your answer better ?!?