# C++: How to resolve implicit declaration compile error?

Tags: c++, c, windows, system

I'm learning C++. With this super basic example, I'm able to perform a PowerShell command.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   system("powershell.exe New-Item -ItemType File -Name cpp_test");
   return 0;
}
```

When compiled in Debian, I get the following (non fatal?) error message:

```
$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc test.c -o test.exe

test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:3:4: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘system’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    system("powershell.exe New-Item -ItemType File -Name cpp_test");
    ^~~~~~
```

I looked up the [implicit declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44993224/warning-implicit-declaration-of-function-system) error but don't quite understand how it applies to my example. Can someone try explaining it to a five yr old...

**Revised**, `test.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
int main() {
   system("powershell.exe New-Item -ItemType File -Name cpp_test");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::system` requires `<cstdlib>`  see - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system

Comment: The answer in the link in your question says you are missing a header.

Comment: I tried that. `fatal error: cstdlib: No such file or directory`

Comment: If you're compiling with a c compiler, you need `<stdlib.h>`

Comment: Lesson 1 in learning C++: C is not C++. Are you sure, your compiler treats .c files as C++? If not, you should rename them to .cpp. And BTW: If you are talking about c++, there is no need to add C tag.

Comment: @Gerhardh thank you. I think that was the problem. I've revised the test.cpp in my question. Does that look correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C function `system` is declared in the C++ header `<cstdlib>` (or in C in the header `<stdlib.h>`)

So if your program is a C++ program then substitute the header `<stdio.h>` that is not used in your program for

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

Otherwise write

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Supporting the backward compatibility the compiler assumes that the function declared somewhere else and it is unable to check whether the call of the function is correct.

Comment: I tried that. It gives me a fatal error: `fatal error: cstdlib: No such file or directory`

Comment: @null It means that you are compiling your program as a C program. If so then use the header stdlib.h.

Comment: Thank you, that helped clarify things. I was definitely confused about C vs C++. I've revised the test.cpp in my question. Does that look correct?

Comment: @null Yes, it is correct,